# How come I can find hundreds of examples of jquery slideshow navigation and zero w/ prototype/scriptaculous?

Tags: magento, prototypejs, scriptaculous

magento comes bundled with scriptaculous so I figured I'd use those for a simple slideshow with navigation to jump between slides.  -what a mistake, I can't find anything other than pause/play controls.  Why?

EDIT:
To clarify what I mean by "jump between slides" is - i'm looking for buttons like 1 2 3 4 NOT pause, prev, next.

Answer (score 1):

Because there aren't that many people developing with scriptaculous.

The real question is why is Magento bundled (and from what I can tell, pretty tightly coupled) with a lackluster javascript library.

Answer (score 1):

If that's "Why aren't there many slide shows", its because Prototype/Scriptaculous was most widely by the Rails community, so most of the interesting Prototype/Scriptaculous add-ons are confined to Rails applications.

If that's "Why does Magento use Prototype/Scriptaculous", its because the Magento developers saw it as the best way to accomplish their goals.

Comment: i had no idea that, "Prototype/Scriptaculous was most widely by the Rails community"! Kind of off topic but, Magento is written in PHP not Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Roberts, I suspect that no truthful answer would be adequate for you.

Answer (score 0):

There may not be hundreds but there's certainly more than zero.  Here's 3 I found just on the first page of a google [search](http://www.google.com/search?q=scriptaculous+slideshow):

- http://www.davidmassiani.com/horinaja/
- http://www.devduff.com/wordpress/scriptaculous-slideshow-for-blogs-and-websites.php
- http://www.tomdoyletalk.com/2008/10/28/simple-image-gallery-slideshow-with-scriptaculous-and-prototype/

Comment: oooh, that top link looks promising, i've seen the other two and they do not have navigation for jumping between slides, just pause next and back.  Thanks though.

Comment: @robert: The demo from that last link had Next and Previous buttons, I thought that was what you were looking for: http://www.tomdoyletalk.com/simple-gallery/

Comment: no, more like 1 2 3 4 buttons.  Sorry, that's what i meant by "jumping between slides"

Comment: @robert: Ahh, I understand now.  It wouldn't hurt to edit your question and add that clarification.  You may get some better answers.